# how to create multiple tables from a pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis, pivot

I have a pivot table which is generated as below, Name contains the column names and text contains their values, So need to generate multiple tables based on the similar values

Input table

```
ID  Name    text    
1   Name,DOB    John,02/02/1980 
2   FirstName,SSN,City  Ray,987898789,Chicago   
3   Name,DOB    Mary,12/21/1990 
4   FirstName,SSN,City  Cary,987000789,Dallas   
5   PersonID,Code,Zip,Gender,Maritial   1234,A456,23456,M,single    
6   PersonID,Code,Zip,Gender,Maritial   1235,A457,23233,M,single    
7   PersonID,Code,Zip,Gender,Maritial   1236,A458,67675,M,Married
```

So the output tables should be something like

Output table1

```
ID  Name    DOB 
1   john    02/02/1980  
3   Mary    02/02/1980
```

output table 2

```
ID  FirstName   SSN City
2   Ray 987898789   Chicago
4   Cary    987000789   Dallas
```

output table 3

```
ID  PersonID    Zip Gender  Marital 
5   1234    A456    23456   M   Single  
6   1235    A457    23233   M   Single  
7   1236    A458    67675   M   Married
```

Can Some one please help me out on this one. can this be done Either in Sqlserver or MySQL or SSIS ??

Comment: Just hard code each query-type by hand; there is no automated support for this, but it is more tedious than difficult.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to first normalize your `input` table. In SQL Server you can use a recursive CTE to split the data that is in the comma-separated list into rows.

The CTE will be similar to the following:

```
;with cte (id, col, Name_list, value, text_list) as
(
  select id,
    cast(left(Name, charindex(',',Name+',')-1) as varchar(50)) col,
         stuff(Name, 1, charindex(',',Name+','), '') Name_list,
    cast(left(text, charindex(',',text+',')-1) as varchar(50)) value,
         stuff(text, 1, charindex(',',text+','), '') text_list
  from input
  union all
  select id,
    cast(left(Name_list, charindex(',',Name_list+',')-1) as varchar(50)) col,
    stuff(Name_list, 1, charindex(',',Name_list+','), '') Name_list,
    cast(left(text_list, charindex(',',text_list+',')-1) as varchar(50)) value,
         stuff(text_list, 1, charindex(',',text_list+','), '') text_list
  from cte
  where Name_list > ''
    or text_list > ''
) 
select id, col, value
from cte;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87f6f/25). This is going to give you the data in the format:

```
| ID |       COL |      VALUE |
-------------------------------
|  1 |      Name |       John |
|  2 | FirstName |        Ray |
|  3 |      Name |       Mary |
|  4 | FirstName |       Cary |
|  5 |  PersonID |       1234 |
```

Once the data is in that format, you can then PIVOT the data based on the columns that you want in each table.

For example if you want the data for `Table1` you will use:

```
;with cte (id, col, Name_list, value, text_list) as
(
  select id,
    cast(left(Name, charindex(',',Name+',')-1) as varchar(50)) col,
         stuff(Name, 1, charindex(',',Name+','), '') Name_list,
    cast(left(text, charindex(',',text+',')-1) as varchar(50)) value,
         stuff(text, 1, charindex(',',text+','), '') text_list
  from input
  union all
  select id,
    cast(left(Name_list, charindex(',',Name_list+',')-1) as varchar(50)) col,
    stuff(Name_list, 1, charindex(',',Name_list+','), '') Name_list,
    cast(left(text_list, charindex(',',text_list+',')-1) as varchar(50)) value,
         stuff(text_list, 1, charindex(',',text_list+','), '') text_list
  from cte
  where Name_list > ''
    or text_list > ''
) 
select *
-- into table1
from
(
  select id, col, value
  from cte
  where col in ('Name', 'DOB')
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (Name, DOB)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87f6f/26)

You will then replace the column names in each query with the values for the next tables.